# Unusual proof for the spherical cosine rule

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, spherical-geometry, spherical-trigonometry

We have $0\lt a\leq b\leq c\lt \frac{\pi}{2}$, and $A$=($0$, $0$, $1$), $B$=($\sin c$, $0$, $\cos c$) on the unit sphere. Also
$$C_\phi=(\sin b\cos \phi, \sin b\sin \phi,\cos b)$$ is given such that $\lvert AC_\phi\rvert = b$ for all $\phi$

Firstly I need to show $$\exists\, \phi\; with\; \lvert BC_\phi\rvert=a \iff a+b\geq c.$$

Then I must deduce the *spherical cosine rule* from this for a spherical triangle with sides $a,b,c$ and opposite angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ :
$$\cos a =\cos b\cos c +\sin b\sin c\cos \alpha.$$
$\space$

For the first part I have gotten as far as showing that $\lvert BC_\phi \rvert=a $
$$\iff \exists\phi \:with\;\cos \phi = \frac{2-2\cos b\cos c - a^2}{2\sin b\sin c}$$
$$\iff\cos (c+b)\leq1- \frac{a^2}{2}\leq\cos (c-b)\,,$$
But I am unsure where to go from here. I'm thinking that $1- \frac{a^2}{2} \leq \cos a$ may be useful since $\cos a \leq \cos(c-b)$ gives the result, but I cannot see how to show this second inequality.

Any guidance would be great. Thank you!

Comment: This is spherical geometry. I'm pretty sure by $|UV|$ here they mean *arclength along the sphere* between $U$ and $V$, not straightline Euclidean distance in $\Bbb R^3$. You should not have a bare $a$ mixed with cosines of $b$ and $c$.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2860418) ?

Comment: @PaulSinclair that makes sense considering explicitly calculating $\lvert AC_\phi \rvert$ as a Euclidean distance gives $\sqrt{2(1-\cos b)}$. Is there a straightforward way to calculate the arc lengths between these points?

Comment: There is a fairly nice rule for figuring out such distances. Unfortunately, part of your purpose here is to prove that rule, so making use of it in that proof is verboten. Jean Marie's link may be helpful.