# How can I derive $\cos s = \cos x \cdot \cos y$ from the spherical triangle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, recreational-mathematics, spherical-trigonometry

I had read that for a "spherical" triangle i.e. all sides are equal and all angles are 90 degrees if e.g.
[image]

(I am sorry for the crude diagram, didn't know how to make it better)

it is: $\cos s = \cos x \cdot \cos y$

but I am not sure how we come about this.
I think:
$x = s \cdot \cos y$ and $y = s \cdot cos x$ and I assume that we can treat each side as hypotenuse but I can't derive the formula.
I remember that if $x$ and $y$ are very small and we use the series definition for $sin$ and $cos$ and ignoring all $x^2$ and rest terms as very small, we can get $s^2 = x^2 + y^2$ which is the pythagorean theorem.

Is there some way to derive $\cos s = \cos x \cdot \cos y$  from the triangle that I am missing?

Comment: Wikipedia gives two proofs for the [Spherical law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines), which is more general than the one you've given (also note that while it's not possible to shrink $x,y$ in your context of all right angles, the more general [first] spherical law of cosines does reduce to the standard law of cosines, and hence also the Pythagorean theorem, for small angular lengths)

Comment: See if this can be of help: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2860418/255730